# $1+2+3+...+n-1$ sum of the first $n-1$ terms

Tags: summation, solution-verification, arithmetic-progressions

I know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

But if I write
$$S = 1+2+3+\ldots+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)$$ and write $S$ backwards, $$S=(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+\ldots+3+2+1$$
Adding two, $$2S = n+n+\ldots+n $$which is adding n ntimes, $$2S=n^2$$ Thus $$S=\frac{n^2}{2}$$

I think there is a mistake, can you help me find the mistake?

Comment: You miscounted: there are only $n-1$ terms in your sum for $2S$, so $2S=n(n-1)$.

Comment: I just noticed, thank you!

Comment: If your question is mainly about checking your approach (as opposed to asking for any solution of the problem), you should use the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag. See [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info) for a more detailed description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a mistake in your calculation. There are $(n - 1)$ terms in your equation. $$S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ..... (n - 2) + (n - 1)$$ $$S = (n - 1) + (n - 2) + .......3 + 2 + 1$$ Adding both, $$2S = n + n + n + n + n....(upto (n - 1) terms$$ $$\therefore 2S = n(n - 1)$$ $$\therefore S = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$$ This is your final answer. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 3):

$n+n+n...$

*"...which is adding $n$ times"*
You're adding it for $n-1$ times!!